# CodeIgniter public_html remove slug

Tags: apache, codeigniter, routes

i have problem to remove public_html slug in url

It look like this

```
http://shirodailynews.esy.es/public_html/about
```

But i want to be like this

```
http://shirodailynews.esy.es/about
```

My current .htaccess in public_html

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

My structure file is like this:

```
system
application
public_html
    css
    js
    img
```

I also configured the system and application path like this

```
$system_path = '../system';
$application_folder = '../application';
```

When I access the main url it not showing the public_html

```
http://shirodailynews.esy.es/
```

but when I access the another link it redirect it using public_html slug.

```
http://shirodailynews.esy.es/public_html/about
```

How I remove the public_html slug in the url? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your webroot's not `public_html`, so precisely, you probably need to just put the index.php and the .htaccess file in the directory below it.